# Как отключить lock на процессоре на сброс мощности?

Tags: amd, процессор

У меня процессор `fx-8350` когда он нагревается до `61 градуса`, то сбрасывает мощность и все сильно лагает, пока он не охладится до `30-35 градусов`. Как повысить порог этого сброса, хотя бы до `70-75 градусов`? В биос в hw заходил и там подобной опции нет.

Comment: Если в БИОСе нет опции, то никак. Попробуйте заменить термопасту и поставить вентилятор помощнее. Или даже систему водяного охлаждения. Или серверный элемент пельтье помощнее. Да и вообще, повышать порог это чревато, процессор может сгореть. Если производитель установил такой порог, значит так и надо.

Comment: Скорее всего, это не производитель. Я посмотрел документацию по процу и там написано, что до 75 градусов может нормально греться и это вполне нормсльно. Нашёл некоторую информацию про материнку, возможно, она не даёт необходимое питание, только что надо повысить , чтобы давала ? У меня слабая материнка - M5A78L-M

Answer (score 0):

> Скорее всего, это не производитель

Это производитель материнки, а не производитель процессора установил такой температурный порог. И производитель материнки установил такой температурный порог руководствуясь документацией на процессор.

> только что надо повысить , чтобы давала

Если в БИОС-е есть пункт "повысить напряжение питания", то повысить напряжение питания можно. Если БИОС-е нет такого пункта, то только перепаивать элементы на материнке, что категорически не рекомендуется делать обычным пользователям.

> У меня слабая материнка - M5A78L-M

Что значит "слабая материнка"? Если заявлено, что материнка поддерживает этот процессор, значит она должна с ним работать. Да и сброс частоты по перегреву это не показатель слабости материнки.

Действительно, может быть что материнка поддерживает этот процессор, но Ваш конкретный экземпляр материнки бракованный и, например, при повышении температуры процессор начинает больше потреблять, а источник на материнке не справляется. Но при такой неисправности обычно система не лагает и не снижает частоту, а намертво виснет. Если же у Вас срабатывает именно подсистема снижения частоты по перегреву, значит все подсистемы у Вас функционируют. Поставьте программу диагностики и поглядите, действительно ли снижается частота процессора при перегреве?

Comment: "Слабая материнка" - под этим выражением я имел ввиду, что она не может раскрыть весь потенциал процессора. Под `fx-8350` написано, что температура 65-70 градусов это вполне нормальное явление, материнка не позволяет ему так греться и там еще несколько пунктов... Но все это уже неважно, смотрите, что я выяснил

Comment: У меня конденсаторы на материнке, которые около процессора очень горячие, они не вздутые, но очень горячие и температура процессора меньше 50 градусов не падает, температура материнки не поднимается выше 40 градусов. Может материнка как-то неисправно подавать напряжение на проц, что из-за этого он не охлаждается?

Comment: И не только конденсаторы , но и вся материнка и там далеко не 50 градусов.. Хотя температуру материнки показывает ~38 градусов при этом. Или может процессор нагревать так материнку и конденсаторы?

Comment: А у Вас в документации на материнку сказано, что она поддерживает этот процессор?

Comment: Ну естественно, 4 года как то все работало

Comment: @Maks Ohotnikov Может быть у Вас 4 года материнка не в режиме работала с процессором который она не поддерживает. И накрылась из-за этого. Нужно, чтобы в документации на материнку в списке поддерживаемых процессоров явно был указан Ваш процессор.

Comment: Т.е. если если сокет подходит это не означает, что проц подходит материнке?

Comment: @Maks Ohotnikov Да, не означает. В простейшем случае производитель процессоров выпускает более мощный камень в старом сокете и наплатный источник на старых платах не тянет этот камень. Ну или тянет, но перегревается и постепенно выходит из строя. Кроме того 4 года это довольно большой срок для материнки. Вполне возможен такой вариант, что, даже если Ваш процессор поддерживается материнкой, просто материнка была не очень качественная и деградировала. Купите новую материнку под этот процессор. Это Вам обойдется в 100 долларов то есть 6000 рублей по нынешним временам.

Comment: @Maks Ohotnikov Но вообще-то не факт, что материнка виновата. Может деградировал сам процессор и перегревается. Чтобы выяснить кто виноват Вам нужна другая машина с таким же сокетом. Переставляя процессор Вы сможете дать диагностику в чем причина сбоев - в процессоре или в материнке. Переставите процессор в другую плату и запустите приложение помощнее или хороший нагрузочный тест и все увидите кто виноват и что делать.

Comment: я купил другую материнку, gigabyеe 970, она под линейку fx. Процессор сейчас в нормальной температуре, но радиаторы на мат. плате раскаленные, это нормально?

Comment: @Maks Ohotnikov Дистанционно трудно сказать. Может действительно процессор слишком много потребляет? Сходите к ремонтникам, посоветуйтесь. У них опыт большой. Там же Вам могут временно поставить другой экземпляр процессора чтобы сравнить температуры.

Comment: В общем, я измерил температуру каждого радиатора, самый горячий 50 градусов. Почитал , пишут , что это вообще нормальная температура. Не понимаю почему на  мат. платах `b450`(для райзена) и еще на некоторых других радиаторы холодные.. Может это из-за `fx`, у линейки этих процессоров очень высокое тепловыделение,так же у них высокая герцовка, видимо, потребляет много энергии и поэтому греется, но это мои догадки.

Comment: В сервис не очень хочу нести, потому что уже отнес и сказали , что проблема в мат. плате и также сказали, что радиаторы на южном мосте не должны быть выше 35 градусов, у меня, что на новой, что на старой около 45. Но, кстати, при новой мат. плате процессор не держит такую высокую температуру, его теперь средняя температура 36 градусов, но материнка все вокруг очень горячее также как и на старой мп.

Comment: Попробуйте где-нибудь на время достать такой же процессор как у вас. Вставьте в свою плату и сравните температуры всех узлов. Если греется только с Вашим экземпляром, значит Ваш экземпляр неисправен. Если греется и с другим экземпляром, значит все нормально так и должно быть.